# SQL Transaction Rollback using TransactionScope in WCF

Tags: sql, wcf, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

I have a web application that is consuming a WCF service.  It is wrapping several method calls in a TransactionScope to prevent corrupted data.  When the web app is used, it appears to succeed in it's method calls because it returns the appropriate data, however; the database does not seem to be committing the data.  Prior to implementing transaction support, all of the methods worked and the data committed.  The service configuration from the web.config file is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpBinding" transactionFlow="true" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="SSOAuthenticationService.SSOUserService">
            <endpoint address="SSOAuthenticationService"
                       binding="wsHttpBinding"
                       contract="SSOAuthenticationService.ISSOUserService"
                       bindingName="wsHttpBinding"
                       listenUri="SSOAuthenticationService"
                       bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

And for the client:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding_SSOUserService" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" transactionFlow="True" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://ssoauthservice.com/SSOUserService.svc/SSOAuthenticationService"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_SSOUserService"
    contract="SSOService.SSOUserService" name="wsHttpBinding_SSOUserService">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="SSOAuthServiceDev@local" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

The service is using a code first EF database methodology for database access.  I'm not sure what other information to include but hope someone has some idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Is the transaction being committed? If not, it will be automatically rolled back.

Comment: Yes, on a successful web method call, the transaction scope in the web app is being committed using the Complete method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late and you probability managed to solve it but if not, at the client application, try to initiate the service proxy before initiating the transaction scope